# How can I use a 'rational section' to compute the Weil divisor associated to a line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}}$
I know there are already questions about this, and this isn't very specific I am just having a hard time grasping this concept. Let us define a *rational section* of an invertible sheaf $\L$ on a (nice: regular, noetherian, integral) scheme $X$ to be a section $s \in U$ where $U$ is a dense open set. Now let $U_1, \dots, U_n$ be a trivializing open cover. Now each $s|_{U_i \cap U}$ can be mapped through the trivialization to give a rational function $f_i$ on $U_i$ so we define the divisor of $s$ to be $$(s) = \sum \nu_Y(f_i) \cdot Y$$ where the sum is taken over all prime divisors $Y$. This sum makes sense since the $f_i$ differs by an invertible function on the overlaps and each $Y$ intersects with some $U_i$.

Is this the correct way to interpret the divisor of a rational section? Is it always necessary to find a trivializing open cover when you do this calculation?

Thank you!